# Clarification on how decision trees split up categorical variables?

Tags: machine-learning

I am hoping to get a point of clarification on how decision trees split up data based on a categorical predictor.

Let's say you have a nominal predictor, with levels [A, B, C, D, E].   When splitting, are the resulting nodes more distinct? For example, we end up with: [A, B], [C, D, E]

Or do we split it so that only one level is exclusively in one node while all the others can show up in both?  For example: [A, B, C, D, E], [B, C, D, E]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tree-based models use recursive binary splitting based on some criterion (e.g. Gini impurity). Whichever variable can be split such that the criterion is maximized, is used.

If you encode a categorical variable, you generally use one-hot encoding: If you have $k$ categories, they are turned into $k$ indicator variables.$^\dagger$

This means that a selection like $[A, B]$ or $[C, D, E]$ is not possible, because that would use the indicator variable of categories $A$ and $B$ simultaneously. Instead, a split occurs as one-vs-all (e.g. $[A]$ or $[B, C, D, E]$.

Of course the next split on could use the indicator variable of another category in the branch that wasn't the category used first.

---

$\dagger$: Unless of course, you use sparse encoding, in which case you use $k-1$ (e.g. to avoid the dummy variable trap).

Comment: In ISLR, he doesn't go into detail about it so I got confused.  But he does say that: "In our discussion thus far, we have assumed that the predictor variables take on continuous values. However, decision trees can be constructed even in the presence of qualitative predictor variables. For instance, in the Heart data, some of the predictors, such as Sex, Thal (Thallium stress test), and ChestPain, are qualitative. Therefore, a split on one of these variables amounts to assigning some of the qualitative values to one branch and assigning the remaining to the other branch."

Comment: Seems like it implies that we could have multiple levels in each of the two branches.  I just didn't know how exactly it would be split, i.e. each branch has levels that are exclusive to that branch, or only a single level is exclusive and the others can be shared.